# Connecting to local SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Suppose I have created a SQL Server database called `Database1.mdf` in the `App_Data` folder in Visual Studio with a table called `Names`.

How could I establish a connection to read the table values using C#?

So far I've tried something like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Database1;");

conn.Open();

// create a SqlCommand object for this connection
SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "Select * from Names";
```

But I get an error:

> *database not found/error connecting to database*

Comment: Did you attach DB to SQL Server?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `Data Source` (on the left of Visual Studio) right click on the database, then `Configure Data Source With Wizard`. A new window will appear, expand the Connection string, you can find the connection string in there

Comment: To display the data source window: On the menu bar, choose View, Other Windows, Data Sources (or choose the Shift+Alt+D keys).

Answer (score 8):

If you use **SQL authentication**, use this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
     "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;" + 
     "User Instance=true;" + 
     "User Id=UserName;" + 
     "Password=Secret;" + 
     "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;"
conn.Open();
```

If you use **Windows authentication**, use this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
     "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;" + 
     "User Instance=true;" + 
     "Integrated Security=true;" + 
     "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;"
conn.Open();
```

Comment: If you are not using named instance, then simply use dot like this `"Data Source=."`

Comment: I used this for SQLEXPRESS `connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"` from MSDN here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#sse

Answer (score 5):

If you're using SQL Server express, change

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;" 
       + "Database=Database1;");
```

to

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\SQLExpress;" 
       + "Database=Database1;");
```

That, and hundreds more connection strings can be found at http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 4):

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost; 
                           Initial Catalog=Northwind; Integrated Security=True");
```

Answer (score 3):

You try with this string connection

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the handy process outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to build connection strings using a .udl file.  This allows you to test them from within the udl file to ensure that you can connect before you run any code.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Visual Studio 2019 (and probably a few previous versions).**

- View -> SQL Server Object Explorer
- Top of the tree is 'SQL Server'
- Under 'SQL Server', are couple of '(localdb)....'
- Expand the *(localdb)... -> Databases*  until you find your db.
- *Database Name (eg. Database1)* -> Right-click -> Properties, and scroll the many properties (eg. "ANSI
  NULL Default"). Find the "Connection string" property, copy the value
  into your code, and you're running.