# Data Access to SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I realise that this is something of a large question that has many potential answers but I would really appreciate some opinions.

I'm writing an app that needs to connect to a SQL Server DB, query for data from two or three tables, do some processing on that data and then update one of those tables.  There isn't really a requirement for a front end as such at the moment so it would be contained in a console app.

So, my question is, what method is currently thought of as 'best' for ease of connection to SQL Server (2008) and data processing?

Any thoughts, decent tuorials etc. would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: SSIS or maybe even CLR stored procs could be worthwhile investigating.

Comment: "help, I do not want to read documentation"? Is that the gist of the question?

Comment: No, as I said in the post, any pointers to tutorials (including documentation) would be great.  It's dificult to read documentation when you don't know what's out there to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) might help you out, I don't know how far you got into using SQL access with C#, so I guess you should start by the basics.

As far for going with what is the best method of doing so, I suppose it is based on opinion, I do it like it is in the example I referenced.

Comment: Thanks Steven, that's given me a good starting point and some ideas on how to progress.

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend looking through some of the tutorials on [CodeProject](http://CodeProject.com)

From a quick search of the website this might be a good tutorial to make a start with.

[Beginners Guide to Acessing SQL Server through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, link only answers are discouraged, so kindly post some more relevant information from the link here too. :)

Answer (score 0):

read this page for connect to your sql server.

**[Connecting to local SQL Server database using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220865/connecting-to-local-sql-server-database-using-c-sharp)**