# Can't connect to local database using C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to database and I've been following a few tutorials but I'm stuck with trying to connect to my database using compact edition that I created in Visual Studio.

I'm trying to connect to the database by:

```
string connection = "Data Source=C:/Users/PLOW/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/File Name/File Name/Users.sdf";

// Making SQL connection
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
cn.Open();
```

Doing so I get this error:

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible..."

I tried:

```
string connection = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Users.sdf";
```

and I get the same error. I don't know how connect it at this point.

This are my connection string:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to local SQL Server database using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220865/connecting-to-local-sql-server-database-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using compact edition, so `SqlConnection` object is not needed here, instead use `SqlCeConnection` and add reference to `System.Data.SqlServerCe`.

Use `SqlCeCommand` instead of `SqlCommand`

Comment: Tested it and that worked. Connection is establish. However, that through up another error in: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlAddUserPass, cn); sqlAddUserPass is insert querie

Comment: I'm trying to insert data by using SqlCommand but I get overload error because I changed the connection to SqlCeConnection. Nonetheless, you answered my initial questions so I'm marking it as answered.

Comment: use `SqlCeCommand` instead of `SqlCommand` and inform me whether it is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

if it's Connectionstring issue, You must declare required parameters to generate connectionstring

```
Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=True;User ID=userName;Password=password
```